# require java false for jRuby osx

Tags: jruby

I have installed jRuby. I don't know what's the issue have. I installed jRuby with rbenv on OSX.

echo $JAVA_HOME has not output

```
❯ rbenv versions
  system
  1.9.3-p125
* 2.2.3 (set by /usr/local/var/rbenv/version)
  jruby-9.0.5.0

~
❯ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

~
❯ rbenv shell jruby-9.0.5.0

~
❯ rbenv version
jruby-9.0.5.0 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)

~
❯ ruby -v
jruby 9.0.5.0 (2.2.3) 2016-01-26 7bee00d Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.45-b02 on 1.8.0_45-b14 +jit [darwin-x86_64]

~
❯ jirb
irb(main):001:0> require 'java'
=> false
irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using JRuby `require 'java'` would have raised an error on MRI

`ruby -v` output confirms that a JVM was found (no need for `JAVA_HOME`)